# R - find name in string that matches a lookup field using regex

Tags: sql, regex, r, gsub, stringr

I have a data frame of ad listings for pets:

```
ID    Ad_title
1     1 year old ball python
2     Young red Blood python. - For Sale
3     1 Year Old Male Bearded Dragon - For Sale
```

I would like take the common name in the Ad_listing (i.e. ball pyton) and create a new field with the Latin name for the species. To assist, I have another data frame that has the latin names and common names:

```
ID    Latin_name           Common_name
1     Python regius        E: Ball Python, Royal Python G: Königspython
2     Python brongersmai   E: Red Blood Python, Malaysian Blood Python
3     Pogona barbata       E: Eastern Bearded Dragon, Bearded Dragon
```

How can I go about doing this? The tricky part is that the common names are hidden in between text both in the ad listing and in the Common_name. If that were not the case I could just use %in%. If there was a way/function to use regex I think that would be helpful.

Comment: Your input files are all in string, right? Have you tried to modify the second data frame so that it becomes a list/vector of all common names?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer does a good job outlining the general logic, so here's a few thoughts on a simple (though not optimized!!) way to do this:

First, you'll want to make a big table, two columns of all 'common names' (each name gets its own row) alongside it's Latin name. You could also make a dictionary here, but I like tables.

```
    reference_table <- data.frame(common = c("cat", "kitty", "dog"), technical = c("feline", "feline", "canine"))

  common technical
1    cat    feline
2  kitty    feline
3    dog    canine
```

From here, just loop through every element of "ad_title" (use apply() or a for loop, depending on your preference). Now use something like this:

```
apply(reference_table,1, function(X) {
if (length(grep(X$common, ad_title)) > 0){ #If the common name was found in the ad_title
[code to replace the string]})
```

For inserting the new string, play with your regular regex tools. Alternatively, play with strsplit(ad_title, X$common).  You'll be able to rebuild the ad_title using paste(), and the parts that make up the strsplit.

Again, this is NOT the best way to do this, but hopefully the logic is simple.

Comment: The logic helped me out a lot, thanks. My problem is though sometimes the common name in the ad listings are spelled slightly different than in the lookup table and therefore grep doesn't count it. For example, in the ad it could be "Bearded-Dragon", but it's not picked up by grep because in the lookup it's "Bearded Dragon". I fear I may need to build custom regexes for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried to create a workable solution for your requirement. There could be better ways to execute it, though, probably using packages such as `data.table` and/or `stringr`. Anyway, this snippet could be a working starting point. Oh, and I modified the `Ad_title` data a bit so that the species names are in titlecase.

```
# Re-create data
Ad_title <- c("1 year old Ball Python", "Young Red Blood Python. - For Sale",
              "1 Year Old Male Bearded Dragon - For Sale")
df2 <- data.frame(Latin_name = c("Python regius", "Python brongersmai", "Pogona barbata"),
                  Common_name = c("E: Ball Python, Royal Python G: Königspython",
                                  "E: Red Blood Python, Malaysian Blood Python",
                                  "E: Eastern Bearded Dragon, Bearded Dragon"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

# Aggregate common names
Common_name <- paste(df2$Common_name, collapse = ", ")
Common_name <- unlist(strsplit(Common_name, "(E: )|( G: )|(, )"))
Common_name <- Common_name[Common_name != ""]

# Data frame latin names vs common names
df3 <- data.frame(Common_name, Latin_name = sapply(Common_name, grep, df2$Common_name),
                  row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = F)
df3$Latin_name <- df2$Latin_name[df3$Latin_name]

# Data frame Ad vs common names
Ad_Common_name <- unlist(sapply(Common_name, grep, Ad_title))
df4 <- data.frame(Ad_title, Common_name = sapply(1:3, function(i) names(Ad_Common_name[Ad_Common_name==i])),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

obviously you need a loop structure for all your common name lookup table and another loop that splits this compound field on comma, before doing simple regex. there's no sane regex that will do it all.
in future avoid using packed/compound structures that require packing and unpacking. it looks fine for human consumption but semantically and for computer program consumption, you have multiple data values packed in single field, i.e. it's not "common name" it's "common names" delimited by comma, that you have there.

sorry if i haven't provided R or whatever specific answer. I'm a technology veteran and use many languages/technologies depending on problem and available resources. you will need to iterate over every record of your latin names lookup table, within which you will need to iterate over the comma delimited packed field of "common names", so you're working with one common name at a time. with that single common name you search/replace using regex or whatever means available to you, over the whole input file. it's plain and simple that you need to start at it from that end, i.e. the lookup table. you need to iterlate/loop through that. iteration/looping should be familiar to you, as it's a basic building block of any program/script. this kind of procedural logic is not part of the capability (or desired functionality) of regex itself. I assume you know how to create a iterative construct in R or whatever you're using for this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by loop structure? Also, I wish my data was structured better - it wasn't a choice for it to be this way.